# get which are checked in list of checkboxes AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp-classic

I would like to get which checkbox are selected by the user, i have this table but it dosen't work. is there any alternative ?

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="max-height: 500px; overflow-y: auto" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th> Nom Exigence</th>
        <th> Verifier</th>

    </tr>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="item in list" style="background-color: #F5F5F5">
        <td>
            {{item.Nom}}
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="user.list" />
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

verify
    Close

when i try to log the $scoepe.user.list it shows me []
this is the modal controller

```
app.controller('ModalInstanceExigencesCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, list) {

$scope.list = [];
$scope.user = [];


for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    $scope.list.push(list[i]);

}

console.log($scope.list);

$scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close();
};

$scope.cancel = function () {

    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};
$scope.verify = function () {

    console.log($scope.user);
};
```

});

Answer (score 0):

this Fiddle should do the job for u: [jsfiddle example using checkboxes](http://jsfiddle.net/gVpgU/25/)

Html-Code (pretty similiar to ur code):

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="item in items">
       <label class="checkbox">
           <input type="checkbox" ng-model="items[$index].checked" />
           {{item.name}}
       </label>
   </li>
</ul>
<hr class="space clearfix" />
{{items | json}}
```

JS-Code:

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

function MainCtrl( $scope )
{
    $scope.items = [
        { name:'foo', checked: true },
        { name:'bar' },
        { name:'baz' }
    ];
}
```

I just define one $scope Object called `items`. In my example each item has a name and optional a value `checked`, which determines wether a checkbox is checked or not.

Html is pretty forward, we repeat over all `items` and then bind our checkbox model `ng-model="items[$index].checked"`. `$index` gives us the number of iteration, for example our first iteration binds to ng-model="items[0].checked"

Hope that helps.

Comment: the $scope.item in my case is dynamic and i don't know how many objects it includes.

Comment: Well, mine was only an example with 3 items. U can add as many as u like dynamically. I think I don't get the problem exactly. Where is the problem with a dynamic number of items?
Edit: I didn't see ur using checklist-model, my fault.
According to the official documentation, I think u forgot `checklist-value="item"` [Official Documentation](http://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/)

My first solution should work, without using checklist-model.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by using this way also

Html-Code:

```js
$scope.collectNumbers = function (contact, index) {
  
   if (contact.IsChecked) {
     }
  else{
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<tr class="" ng-repeat="contact in Contacts">
     <td>
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="contact.IsChecked" ng-change="collectNumbers(contact,$index)" ng-checked="contact.IsChecked">
        </label>
     </td>
     <td>{{contact.Name}}</a></td>
</tr>
```